# Strange google gmail activity logs

Tags: gmail

So I was reviewing the recent activity logs on my GMail account and came across an IPv6 address:

```
United States (IL) (2607:fb90:1704:602f:4b7d:75c3:d50f:2fd4)
```

I live in another state, so how can this be possible if the type was of mobile access. When I look at ARIN search I get:

http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET6-2607-FB90-1/pft

T-Mobile is accessing my GMail account? Is that weird or no?

Updates:

- Yes, I have T-Mobile as my phone provider.
- Everytime I access GMail from my phone, it lists the correct IP of my state, the ones from Illinois are from completely different days.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, when you are connected to a wireless AP the gmail applications default to using the better connection so it uses the routers located here with their IP.

When I m connected to the T-Mobile network I send it over to the company in Illinois.

I know it seems self evident but both my work and home connections are remembered on the phone and there's no where else i use it much so it makes sense to see the sporadic dates associated with that IPv6.

Still interesting to know where my data goes when I'm connected to their network.